# Connecting to mailserver over an intranet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, smtp, smtpclient

### Problem:

I am trying to connect to a remote mailserver to send emails from an ASP.NET MVC 4 app.  Despite using the details that my client has given me to setup the web.config, I am getting the following error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25
```

### Setup:

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 website that needs to send emails.  The mailserver is NOT installed on the same box as the webserver.

There is no smtp client or server installed on the webserver.  Is this needed?

The client has little experience with hosting their own webserver.  I have always connected to mail servers using the hosting companies instructions.  This company does not seem to have anyone with the expertise.  I am an external consultant, with no experience in networks or mailservers.

### Web.Config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="systems@medreport.co.uk">
        <network host="MYHOST1" userName="MyUser" password="PASSWORD" clientDomain="myhost1.mydomain.co.uk" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

### My reasoning:

From the error, it seems that the ASP.NET MVC app is looking for a mailserver on the localhost machine, ie, the same machine as the webserver.  It isn't there, so I get the error.

If that is correct, then there must be something wrong with the attributes of the  tag in my web.config.  These attributes are not pointing at a valid server, so I am presuming that the system is defaulting to a mailserver on localhost.  Is this reasoning correct?

### Questions:

1. I may not have been given the correct name for the `host` or for the `clientDomain` attributes of the `<network>` tag.  As a result, the mvc app tries to find a mailserver on localhost.  Is this reasoning correct?
2. I have been given a clientDomain name of the type clientDomain="myhost1.mydomain.co.uk".  However, I am trying to connect not over the internet, but over the client's intranet.  Should I not have a clientDomain attribute that reflects that I am connecting over an intranet?
3. The website uses SSL.  I have tried using the enableSsl attribute to no avail.  However, I presume that the enableSsl attribute relates to communication with the mailserver, not the webserver. Is this correct?  As the mail server is on their internal network, they aren't, I understand, using SSL for the mailserver.
4. An alternative theory would be that there is a firewall issue that is bouncing me out of the mailserver box.  But surely I would get a more specific error if that were the case...?

### EDIT:

Do I need to install SMTPclient on the webserver for it to be able to connect to the mailserver on a different box?

Comment: What's the host that they've given you? Can you ping it? Can you try using `<network defaultCredentials="false" host="MYHOST1" password="PASSWORD" userName="MyUser" />`?

Comment: @RowanFreeman: I can ping the IP address, but when I use the url they gave, I get:  Ping request could not find host.  Please check the name and try again.  Yes, I have tried the network tag attributes you mention, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @RowanFreeman: A question - do I need to install SMTPclient on the web server for it to be able to connect to the mailserver?

Comment: What is the message from the command: `telnet yourSMTPServer 25` ?

Comment: @BrOSs: 'telnet' is recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  As stated above, the mailserver is on a different box on their intranet.

Comment: you'd never be able to send any email until you get something like: `220 test.auto.mySMTPserver.com ESMTP Service (Lotus Domino Release 8.5.3FP2 HF95) ready at Tue, 02 Apr 2013 08:27:31 -0700` on telnet command. So, you should focus on open up that connection.

Comment: @BrOSs: my main problem is that their network guy is away and the onsite people have never done this before.  Neither have I to be truthful.

Comment: @BrOSs:  OK, got telnet to show the kind of message you mentioned, but I still get the same error message when trying to send an email.  Could it be a firewall messing things up?

Comment: @BrOSs: ...or do I need some kind of SMTP service on the IIS box?

Comment: About your last question, No you don't need a SMTP service in your IIS. And if you've got the message you're done (not firewall is messing now). Just curious, are you able to send emails already?

Comment: @BrOSs:  Yes, it is all working now.  Happy ending.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have solved this problem:  I had the following code in my mail sending routine:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
client.Send(message);
```

Note the hardcoded `"localhost"`.

The only problem is that now it gives me the following error:

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for abc@xyz.efg
```

But that, as the Jungle Book would say, is another story.